# How to cache mysql stored functions

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, stored-functions

I have a mysql query that uses stored functions to do some heavy math for reports. I need to use that stored function like 4 or 5 times in the same query.  But the function needs data from the iteration, so I can't set it as a variable.

Is there any way that you know of, to cache the function if the parameters are the same? We could build this in ourselves, check the parameters and a cache table, and if they are the same, just return immediately. But I'm wondering if MySql has this built in. Were using MariaDB 10

here is an example of the function calls

```
dailySales2(sku.sku) as daily,
countOrders(sku.sku,90) as sold90,
ROUND(getStock(sku.sku) / dailySales2(sku.sku)) as daysOfStock,
getStock(sku.sku) as stock,
ROUND(GREATEST(1,qb.moq,(dailySales2(sku.sku) * (ROP + 5)) - (getStock(sku.sku)))) as   toOrder,
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a nested query?

Before:

```
SELECT sproc(col), ROUND(sproc(col)) FROM tbl
```

After:

```
SELECT result, ROUND(result) FROM
(SELECT sproc(col) FROM tbl) AS nested
```

Comment: potentially I could use an inner query to set a bunch of @variables and then the outer query to do the logic. Not sure if that would work, but it's something to think about.